# Use wordpress with a Java Spring application

Tags: java, wordpress, spring

For a school project we need to create a Web app with Java and Spring. We also need some sort of cms so we wanted to use wordpress in our app. I have searched for a way to use wordpress within our application but can't seem to find the fitting answer.

Please help :)

Comment: hi, please read [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question is too broad, consider asking on some other site or stack-[exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: What do you mean with "we wanted to use wp in our app"?

WP and Java are two different worlds. You can't extend WP with Java and you can't (easily) publish in WP with Java.

I imagine rest api (wrote in java) feeding your WP page. To do so you should write your own template (in php), ...

Backwards you could need to show the n-th item of your WP blog in you web app. In this scenario you should need of a WP service layer and I don't know (I don't think so) if it is exists.

So, first of all, be clear what you need.

Comment: Hey. Sorry this isn't the sort of site where you can ask broad advice on such topics. If / when you encounter a specific programming problem, with code which can be used to reproduce an error, then you will find help here.

Answer (score -1):

Since Wordpress is a PHP-based application, you cannot use it directly in Java web app. Depending on your needs, you might be able to integrate the two by running your Java web application side-by-side with PHP server with Wordpress and share the data via database.